# PayPal Mobile Payments, Logins, MPL and MEP files for iOS and PhoneGap

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, paypal

I'm trying to set up a mobile PayPal payment for gift cards in an iPhone app using the PhoneGap PayPal plugin but I'm hitting a brick wall:

- I can launch a payment and get to the PayPal screen on the simulator but no combination of logins will work for me. I have verified these logins minutes earlier on the PayPal sandbox test site. I am using the sandbox App-ID and ENV_SANDBOX. I am also logged into my sandbox account on my Mac while doing this.
- The log in XCode shows the payment message with all the correct price, items details, etc.
- I have whitelisted th PayPal sites and I don't get whitelist messages in the log.
- On my iPhone 4 with iOS 5.0 I cannot get to the PayPal screen. The log shows the "FILE SYSTEM CHECK ERROR" message. I have read elsewhere that this is to do with jailbroken phones but my phone is definitely not jailbroken.

I have tried just about every combination of ideas I can find but to no avail. So I have to ask:

- Does the sandbox work OK for PayPal mobile payments? Has anyone got a successful login sequence?
- The PhoneGap plugin uses a PayPal library file ending in "MEP" but the latest PayPal library uses an "MPL" suffix (or MEC for express checkout). Some of the function calls appear different between MEP and MPL as well. Is this a difference in versions and the PhoneGap plugin is just running an old version library? If so, is this likely to be a cause of issues?

Comment: Does the same for me on iOS 4.3 on iPad, FILE SYSTEM CHECK ERROR in log.  Although it does work in the simulator and completes the transaction in sandbox. I'd be interested in the answer to MEP vs MPL.

Answer (score 0):

I've only tried the MECL library at the moment, because our customer already had a working server backend.

Dunno if this can be of any use to you, but you may have a shot at https://github.com/azicchetti/MECLPayPalPlugin

Unfortunately it doesn't use the MPL library and you need some backend code to complete the express checkout flow. It works, though.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your fake accounts inside your sandbox?
The login when trying to test paying on the sandbox is NOT your paypal.com login, and is NOT your developer.paypal.com login.

Additionally, you must FIRST log into developer.paypal.com before your fake sandbox accounts will be recognized by the sandbox... This might be hard to do on a mobile device.